# Save Sent SendGrid Emails as PDF

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am using SendGrid's API via Python and my current project requires that I save each email that gets sent and upload it to another website (Limited to certain file types such as PDFs and .docs).

Is there a simple way to do this? The emails being sent use a dynamic template, so I don't think I can just grab the html_content and convert it to a PDF.

I am sending the emails by passing a json of the dynamic data and the template ID into a Mail Helper object